Logicapp designer in visual studio code becomes entangeled
I just finished my logic app zoomed out and voila :

Im using Visual studio Code and developing using the designer and logic app extenstion there. Is this a bug or somthing ? how can i fix it ?
I saved all my steps using the save button, no commits unfortunately. I cant use ctrl - z, left clicking on the workflow.json file shows no local saved files even tough i did, ive tried restarting visual studio code. Is there anything left that i can try, or do i just need to manually do everything over again.

My question might be a bit off-topic here, but what are the benefits of developing Logic Apps in VS Code instead of directly in Azure? Perhaps @Skin could also weigh in. Historically, I've always preferred developing Logic Apps in Azure and haven't found a compelling reason to do it in VS Code. While there might be special cases where some code needs to be deployed first, the basic workflow can always be fine-tuned in Azure and then copied to VS Code / checked into Git.

Its a good question! ive always been developing in the portal my self, but my new workplace does it this way so i gave it a try. The benefit of it is that you can develop the functions and logicapp in the same workspace and use local functions quit easy without using postman or any other hassle.  Visual studio Code has somthing called Thunder Client for testing http requests. So short answer you get the entire "app" in the same enviroment with testing tools.

It’s a bug and a terrible one at that.
I’ve spoken to the product manager at Microsoft about it and they are aware but even then, that was two months ago.
It happens when dependencies within containers (e.g. Do until loops, For each loops, scopes, etc.) get confused and don’t save properly.
It happens to me the most when I move scope containers around, the actions contained within or rename them after the fact. You have to be very careful when doing that.
Until it’s fixed, you can take some steps to recover your workflow when this happens:

Take regular backups of your workflow.json file. Simply copy and paste the json to a new file and do it regularly.
If you’re using Git to manage your changes, commit regularly so you can rollback.

If you need to fix an existing file because you can’t roll back easily, you’ll need to edit the workflow.json manually, however, this is no easy task depending on your workflows complexity.
You need to analyse the runAfter settings and also if there is a container that inadvertently has the same name.
It happens to me a lot and I’ve learned to live with it but unfortunately, the recovery process without a backup isn’t a friendly one.
